# Best practice: Class implements a couple of Observers

Tags: java

There are a couple of Listeners `L1, L2, ...` all similar:

```
interface L1 { void onL1(); }
interface L2 { void onL2(); }
...
```

All are used in class `EventMaker` like this:

```
class EventMaker {
  ...
  List<L1> l1s = new LinkedList<>();
  List<L2> l2s = new LinkedList<>();
  ...
  void addL1(L1 l1) {...; l1s.add(l1); ...;}
  void removeL1(L1 l1) {...; l1s.remove(l1); ...;}
  void callL1() {...}

  void addL2(L2 l2) {l2s.add(l2);}
  void removeL2(L2 l2) {l2s.remove(l2);}
  void callL2() {...}
  ...

}
```

What can I do, to reduce the repeating code? I tried to use generic methods, but it is no solution in many ways.

// ************************************************************************

My Solution:

```
abstract class Caller<Listener> {

    List<Listener> listeners;

    public Caller() {
        listeners = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public void add(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void remove(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void call() {
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            onCall(listener);
        }
    }

    public abstract void onCall(Listener listener);

}
```

Empty Listener-Interface:

```
interface Listener {    
}
```

For Every-Listener:

```
class L1Caller extends Caller<L1> {

    @Override
    public void onCall(L1 listener) {
        listener.l1(); // unique name
    }

}
```

Finally I add for every listern-type a caller to my main-class.

```
...
L1Caller l1Caller;
L2Caller l2Caller;
...
```

And use it like:

```
l1Caller.add(...);
l2Caller.call();
```

Comment: Why do you have to store them in separate lists? If they are so similar, why is there no shared common super class or interface?

Comment: They are similar in logic (add, remove, call), but they are different in meaning (different events).

Comment: Generics would help with the add/remove functionality, but there really isn't an elegant way to replace the 'callLX()` methods short of using reflection (which is overkill here).  Extracting duplicate code to a method for reuse is a good refactoring, but here it seems like you have code that is similar, but not duplicate.  What is the motivation for reducing the lines of code?

Comment: The problem with add\remove is, that another class can implement more than one listener interface. ... My motivation is to remove duplicate code.

Comment: Similar code is not duplicate code.  Reducing lines of code for the sake of reducing lines of code isn't very good motivation.

Your methods look similar, but they are operating on different types and calling different methods.  Generics can get you part of the way there, but you end up writing a bunch of one line methods that call generic versions of some one line methods, and you have to introduce some common interfaces or something similar that may create an artificial relationship between things that really aren't related.

Comment: Then having a single class for the add/remove/call functionality specialised via generics sounds like a possible solution, does it? like `Listener <EventType>`

Comment: Actually I try to understand the other answers. For my solution I can say: The code is completely removed from the main-class and only member-variables are needed for a new listerner/caller. But there are many new classes now .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is best practice, but it's certainly possible.

```
public class Caller {

    public static final Token<L1> L1 = new Token<>();
    public static final Token<L2> L2 = new Token<>();

    public static class Token<T> {
        // Making the constructor private means that no other Tokens can be made.
        private Token() {}
    }

    private final Map<Token<?>, List<Object>> lists;

    public Caller() {
        lists = new HashMap<>();
        Token<?>[] tokens = {L1, L2};
        for (Token<?> token : tokens)
            lists.put(token, new LinkedList<>());
    }

    public <T> void add(Token<T> token, T t) {
        lists.get(token).add(t);
    }

    public <T> void remove(Token<T> token, T t) {
        lists.get(token).remove(t);
    }
}
```

Despite the use of wildcards and `Object`, it's completely type-safe and is easy to use:

```
caller.add(Caller.L1, () -> {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: I coded up something similar and then realized that I'd written about 30 lines of code to save 5.

Comment: @BobbyStJacques I completely agree. I wouldn't actually do this unless there were many different types of `Listener`. 2 certainly doesn't justify it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the existing ChangeListener with its ChangeEvent where the source is of interest. Alterative use generic types.

Then make a class to hold a list of listeners, say

```
public class ChangeManager {
    private final List listeners = ...
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) { ... }
    public void notifyChange(ChangeEvent event) { ... }
}
```

This can handle listeners in a garbage collected and concurrency safe way.

Now your class delegates to several ChangeManagers.

```
private final ChangeManager l1 = new ChangeManager();
private final ChangeManager l2 = new ChangeManager();

private final ChangeEvent L1_EVENT = new ChangeEvent(this);

...
    l1.addChangeListener(changeEvent -> {
        ...
    });

    l1.notifyChange(L1_EVENT);
```

Comment: I used [javax-swing.ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) and its ChengeEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You should retain the individual `add*` methods to your API because they are meaningful and makes for a clearer API. One option which alters your API is to have a single `add(type, listener)` and route all invocations through it. However, then you must expose that type and the client must coordinate on adding the right listener to the right type.

One way to not alter your API but internally manage the listeners in aggregate is a pattern like this:

```
class EventMaker {
  ...
  static String TYPE_L1 = "L1";
  static String TYPE_L2 = "L2";
  Map<String, List<Object>> listeners;
  ...
  void addInternal(String t, Object listener) {
     List<Object> list = listeners.get(t);
     if (list == null) { list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); listeners.put(t, list); }
     list.add(listener);
  }
  void removeInternal(String t, Object listener) {
     List<Object> list = listeners.get(t);
     if (list != null) { list.remove(listener; }
     // optional
     if (list != null && list.isEmpty) listeners.remove(t);
  }
  <ListenerType> List<ListenerType> getInternal(String t, Class<ListenerType> cls) {
     List<Object> list = listeners.get(t);
     if (list == null) return Collections.emptyList();
     return (List<ListenerType>)list;
  }
  void removeInternal(String t, Object listener) {...}
  void addL1(L1 l1) { addInternal(TYPE_L1, l1);}
  void removeL1(L1 l1) { removeInternal(TYPE_L1, l1);}
  void callL1() {
     List<L1> list = getInternal(TYPE_L1, L1.class);
     for (L1 ears : list) ears.onL1();
  }

  void addL2(L2 l2) {addInternal(TYPE_L2, l2);}
  void removeL2(L2 l2) {removeInternal(TYPE_L2, l2);}
  void callL2() {...}
  ...
}
```

The type is ignored in the map since you are protecting everything in and out, and safely cast when accessing one of the listener lists. The type is still necessary when notifying your listeners though since they have no common base. The concurrent-safe `CopyOnWriteArrayList` also has some performance implications worth looking into for listener lists.

I would also recommend returning a handle instead of requiring a removeListener call. This allows the caller to not have to look up the event source when cleaning up, but has an OO handle that does the work. `java.lang.AutoCloseable` (if using Java 7 or later, else `java.lang.Runnable`) is a good choice for this:

```
AutoCloseable addInternal(String t, final Object listener) {
     List<Object> list = listeners.get(t);
     if (list == null) { list = new ArrayList<>(); listeners.put(t, list); }
     list.add(listener);
     final List<Object> flist = list; // for final reference below
     return new AutoCloseable() {
          public void close() { flist.remove(listener); }
     };
}
```

And now the caller operates by simply calling `.close()` on that returned handle to unregister.

And a simpler handle if you are using Java 8:

```
AutoCloseable addInternal(String t, final Object listener) {
     List<Object> list = listeners.get(t);
     if (list == null) { list = new ArrayList<>(); listeners.put(t, list); }
     list.add(listener);
     return () -> list.remove(listener);
}
```

You also should look into properly synchronizing to ensure thread-safety if it is a concern, making your fields private and final as appropriate, and other good-practice cleanup I did not address in those examples.